# How would I make a like button?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, social-networking

I am working on making a social media app clone using tutorials for practice in Swift, but I want to add a like button with Parse but not sure how. Does anyone know a tutorial or do you know how you would go about doing this? I attempted to make one like this but I'm pretty sure it is not correct...

I put this in the cell view controller

```
@IBAction func likeButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    a++

    var post = PFObject(className: "Post")

    post["likes"] = a


}

}
```

This went into the feed view controller...

```
var messages = [String]()
var usernames  = [String]()
var imageFiles = [PFFile]()
var users = [String: String]()
var likesArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var query = PFUser.query()

    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let users = objects {

            self.messages.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.imageFiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.likesArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            for object in users {

                if let user = object as? PFUser {

                    self.users[user.objectId!] = user.username!
                }

            }
        }
    })

    var getFollowedUsersQuery = PFQuery(className: "followers")

    getFollowedUsersQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)

    getFollowedUsersQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects {

            for object in objects {

                var followedUser = object["following"] as! String

                var query = PFQuery(className: "Post")

                query.whereKey("userId", equalTo: followedUser)

                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

                    if let objects = objects {

                        for object in objects {

                            self.messages.append(object["message"] as! String)

                            self.imageFiles.append(object["imageFile"] as! PFFile)

                            self.usernames.append(self.users[object["userId"] as! String]!)

                            self.likesArray.append(object["likes"] as? String)

                            self.tableView.reloadData()


                        }

                    }

                })

            }
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return usernames.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell

    imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

            myCell.postedImage.image = downloadedImage
        }

    }


    myCell.username.text = usernames[indexPath.row]

    myCell.message.text = messages[indexPath.row]

    myCell.likeLabel.text = likesArray[indexPath.row]

    myCell.selectionStyle = .None

    return myCell
}


}
```

This is the view controller when you post the picture and message...

```
var likes = 0

var picSelected = false

@IBOutlet var feed: UIButton!

func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) ->    Void in


    }))

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

@IBOutlet var imageToPost: UIImageView!

@IBAction func chooseImage(sender: AnyObject) {

    var image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false

   presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    imageToPost.image = image

    picSelected = true
}

@IBOutlet var message: UITextField!


@IBAction func postImage(sender: AnyObject) {

    if message.text != "" && picSelected != false  {
    picSelected = false
    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: view.frame)
    activityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

    var post = PFObject(className: "Post")

    post["message"] = message.text

    post["userId"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId!

    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToPost.image)

    let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imageData)

    post["imageFile"] = imageFile

    post["likes"] = a

    post.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in

        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        if error == nil {

            self.displayAlert("Image Posted!", message: "Your image has been posted successfully.")

            self.imageToPost.image = UIImage(named: "Blank-Person1.png")

            self.message.text = ""

        }

    }

    } else {
        displayAlert("Could Not Post Image!", message: "Please enter a message and/or select a picture.")
    }

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm about to make Like button like this:

- Create Names column in parse ( Array column) to hold names who click on like button
- Create Likes column in parse (integer column) to hold count number of Names column

and when someone click on like button add his name to Names Array in parse, If he click it again remove his name

And you need to take all names in NamesArray column and count them in swift then update likes column

i'm not sure but that's in my mind right now, but if you think of it you'll get better way.

Comment: Thanks! If you ever do program it and it works out I would love to see the source code. But yeah seeing that it looks like it's going to work.

Comment: Wait never mind. I figured it out. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @EthanCotler no I've not programmed it, But you can just remove likes column, and just make one column for names, and when someone click on button add his name if he click it again remove his name, and you can count all the Array names to get integer number like 83 likes! , that's mean 83 names in array. that's it.

Comment: Thanks Salah! I will try that out!

Comment: @EthanCotler Anytime, hope if i help you.

Comment: I do have on question though. How would I create the array so that it's different per post?

Comment: @EthanCotler When you create Array in Parse it will be different for each row (for each post) , Take a look at this picture: http://cut.by/rw1H1 .. You'll see Last image posted have 2 likes from Salah and Ethan. You just need to do query to get the Array for each post. And you can call it Likes instead of Names

Comment: Thanks since I am a newb I do understand but I don't understand how to go about doing this. Could I by any chance see a picture of your source code?

Comment: @EthanCotler Querys its different depends on how you would like to view the data from parse in your app. Just make a search in google on how to get data from parse using swift. I don't have source code for this but i've just created New column in parse to show you!